# Почему присвоить значение final переменной можно только через конструктор?

Tags: переменные, java

Поясните пожалуйста момент, почему присвоить значение final переменной можно только через конструктор.

```
public class Human {

    private final String name;

    public Human(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Потому что это единственная гарантия, что пользователь класса проинициализирует поле.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не совсем понятно слово «почему». Вас интересует ссылка на стандарт или мотивация?

Ссылка на стандарт: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html.

> Each local variable (§14.4) and every blank final field (§4.12.4, §8.3.1.2) must have a definitely assigned value when any access of its value occurs.
>
> ...
>
> If V is a blank final field, then only a constructor or an initializer for the class containing the declaration for V can perform assignments to V; no method can perform assignments to V.

Мотивация: переменная должна быть инициализирована перед использованием. Поскольку в общем случае [невозможно](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) во время компиляции выяснить, пойдёт ли код сначала по ветке, в которой поле используется, или по ветке, где оно инициализируется, компилятор может *гарантировать* инициализацию переменной только если она инициализирована в конструкторе или инициализаторе класса.

Компилятор не может возложить гарантию инициализации на программиста, как это делает, например, C++, поскольку это противоречит философии языка: программист не должен иметь возможность привести программу в [непредсказуемое состояние](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Итого:

- формальный ответ: невозможно, так как запрещено стандартом;
- неформальный ответ: невозможно, так как компилятор недостаточно умный, чтобы проверить, что переменная будет инициализирована позже, если не инициализировать её в конструкторе.

Comment: Понял спасибо!

Comment: @Женька Сидоров: Пожалуйста!